# How to draw "clean and simple" vectors on a plane in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, vector

How can I draw vectors on a plane like the ones in the following image in LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways to draw this, here is one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,scale=0.5,line cap=round,
    bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill}]
 \draw[->] (-9,0) -- (9,0) node[right]{$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-7) -- (0,7) node[above]{$y$};
 \draw foreach \X in {3,6}
  {(\X,0.1) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node[below]{$\X$}};
 \draw foreach \Y in {2,4}
  {(0.1,\Y) -- ++ (-0.2,0) node[left]{$\Y$}};
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {(6,2),(3,4)} 
 {\path  \X node(n\Y)[bullet,label=right:{$\X$}]{};
 \draw[thick,->]  (0,0) -- (n\Y);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,scale=0.5,line cap=round,
    bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill}]
 \draw[->] (-9,0) -- (9,0) node[right]{$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-7) -- (0,7) node[above]{$y$};
 \draw foreach \X in {3,6}
  {(\X,0.1) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node[below]{$\X$}};
 \draw foreach \Y in {2,4}
  {(0.1,\Y) -- ++ (-0.2,0) node[left]{$\Y$}};
 \path (0,0) coordinate (O) 
    (6,2) node[bullet,label=right:{$(6,2)$}](A){} 
    (3,4) node[bullet,label=right:{$(3,4)$}](B){} 
    (O) edge[thick,->] (A) edge[thick,->] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is indeed a very clean vector diagram. I see that there are two nodes (3, 4) and (6, 2). Is there a way to label these nodes as A and B?

I labeled the origin node as "O" but I'm stuck on naming the tips of the vectors.

Comment: @Sam I added an example in which the nodes carry the names `A` and `B`. It is also a slightly different approach as the first one.

Answer (score 6):

With the new version `3.02c` of `tkz-euclide` (which I'm discovering for the occasion), you get this:

[image: screenshot]

Some explanations are given as comments in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[vect/.style={->,>={Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}}]
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=6,ymin=-1,ymax=6]% dimensions of the bounding box
\tkzDrawXY[noticks,>=latex]% draw the 2 axis
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(3,4){A}
\tkzDefPoint(6,2){B}
\tkzPointShowCoord[-,xlabel=$3$,ylabel=$4$,thin,gray,xstyle={below=4pt}](A)% show the coordonates
\tkzPointShowCoord[-,xlabel=$6$,ylabel=$2$,thin,gray,xstyle={below=4pt}](B)
\tkzDrawSegments[vect](O,A O,B)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```